# Query SQL database from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm attempting to create a MS Query to return data from a SQL database based on a value from a cell in Excel. I have actually successful accomplished this, but only for 1 row.  I cant figure out how to get it to copy-down to other rows.

I've created a connection as follows:
[image]

Notice that the SQL statement includes a parameter. The parameter is set to point to a specific cell:
[image]

I guess this makes sense as I'm only looking to return 1 value per row:The problem is that I have multiple lines to return values for. How do I return a value per row for multiple rows?

I've tried changing the cell reference in the Parameters dialog box, but this does not work as the Excel Table is designed to grow dynamically.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in Excel without VBA. Using VBA is fairly trivial. Create the server connection using ADODB. Loop through your range with parameters. With each one create specific query; execute query; copy recordset results to cell. You can find lots of ADODB tutorials online. If you have specific issue with your code post it here and we would gladly help. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Excel data connections works in a way that every connection has only one SQL Query. So in order to do what you'r looking for, you will need to have many connections, and that's not the "best practice".
However, there are two ways you can solve this situation:
1. Make a single connection with all of the data and create a pivot table based on it. Then use VLOOKUP/INDEX to gather the data to your requested cells.
2. If the data is too big, you can use VBA code to create a smaller Query based on the cells you mentioned and then continue as described on the first option.

Good luck.